# Routing network traffic thru a Windows machine is very slow

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I have two Windows 10 Pro for Workstations machines connected via Thunderbolt Ethernet and would like to utilize the fast 10GbE connection to NAS server via PC_A to improve transfer rates for PC_B that doesn't have 10GbE adapter. The `10.10.10.0` network is managed by a router connected to a switch.

The requirement is to forward traffic from PC_B to NAS thru PC_A when it is available.

Network topology:

> [image: network topology]

I don't want to bridge interfaces (in case one of the machines are down).

So far I did the following:

1. On PC_A I've enabled routing (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IPEnableRouter=1` and started routing service)
2. On PC_A I've enabled Internet Connection Sharing from `10.10.10.100` interface to fast 20GbE interface which changed its IP to `192.168.137.1`
3. On PC_B I've set 20GbE interface to DHCP which got IP: `192.168.137.27` with gateway `192.168.137.1`
4. On PC_B I've added a static route for NAS IP `route -p add 10.10.10.102 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.137.1 IF 3` (where interface 3 is fast 20GbE one)

The transfer speed is extremely slow about 1MB/s, I have a feeling that "Internet Connection Sharing" isn't actually using Windows router.

When I disable "Internet Connection Sharing" and assign static IP to both sides of the 20GbE connection I can transfer data with full speed, but PC_B can't reach NAS server.

How can I forward traffic via PC_A or increase the speed of "Internet Connection Sharing"?